# GPU not showing up in Blender?

Tags: gpu, linux, hardware

Just installed Zorin OS (a Linux distrubution) and installed Blender. I am running this Linux alongside Windows 10. So I go to the system tab in Blender and see that my GPU is not listed!

[image]

Why is my Nvidia GTX 1050 not showing up in the system tab? Also Blender is super laggy for some reason, could it be connected?

Comment: yes, it is connected, most likely driver issue.

Comment: In linux you need to use the proprietary drivers for the GPU, they don't come installed by default. You will have to google that yourself.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install nvidia-cuda-toolkit because blender uses this toolkit in order to drive your nvidia card.

```
apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit
```

You should also make sure that your nvidia card is cuda compatible.

[blender docs related to GPU.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/fr/dev/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html)

[list of nvidia graphics cards compatible with CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-gpus)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, [asked and answered here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/211701/24959).

It was a CUDA issue. The method described in [Debian docs](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_10_.22Buster.22-1) didn't install properly and I needed to purge everything and download/install CUDA manually from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the latest available graphics drivers for linux by nvidia, since cuda is [supported on the 1050 mobile](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1002580/cuda-on-geforce-gtx-1050-notebook-/)

Edit: I just checked your OS and since it's based on Ubuntu, you might be able to [download nvidia's drivers for ubuntu](https://websiteforstudents.com/install-proprietary-nvidia-gpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-16-04-17-10-18-04/)

Answer (score 0):

How you get nVidia drivers and blender support.

- Follow what [C. Vergnaud][1] said because they are absolutely right!  
       
  But I'd suggest going to [https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads][2] and then choose your distribution.
- After choosing your distribution choose your version.
- choose your installation type.
- If you have non-free rpm fusion or your respective non-free repo for your distribution; make sure to remove the drivers so they don't clash.
- follow the install instructions on the cuda website
- reboot you just updated your kernel; *it's good practice*
- I have Fedora so the command I needed was: `dnf -y install cuda-toolkit-11-7-11.7.0-1.x86_64`
- You will also need to `nvidia-settings` or it won't be installed and if you have multiple monitors they will not both work till `nvidia-settings` is installed.
  Do whatever installs the cuda-toolkit for your system!
- Driver installation: Now you need to install the drivers: `dnf install cuda-drivers-515.43.04-1.x86_64`
  remember to run: `dnf remove xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda-libs-3:510.68.02-1.fc36.x86_64`
  **Congratulations!** You should now have CUDA installed.
  For further reading and information on CUDA installation: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html

Comment: Is there someone that can check why some links and formatting aren't working?

Answer (score -2):

The GTX 1050 mobile series lack a feature called "cuda".

If you have a laptop with a 1050, it will not work.

If you have a desktop with a 1050, it ***should*** work, but you have a different problem.

Comment: Actually, notebook versions of the 1050 are cuda compatible https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1002580/cuda-on-geforce-gtx-1050-notebook-/

Comment: Nvidia has confirmed that the GTX 1050 Mobile does support CUDA with around 620 CUDA cores