# Blender loses contact with NVIDIA drivers after update

Tags: gpu, drivers, linux

Every time I update Linux (Debian 11) headers or drivers, Blender loses contact with my graphics card (NVIDIA GeForce 1060)

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was a NVIDIA issue not syncing with Linux updates and disconnecting Blender's ability to find anything NVIDIA/CUDA related.

To fix:

#### Part I:

- Uninstall NVIDIA & CUDA and start from scratch:
  `$ sudo apt purge nvidia*`
  `$ sudo apt purge cuda*`
- [Download proper NVIDIA drivers](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx)
- [Download proper CUDA toolkit](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit) for your system (I used "deb[local]")
- Before **installing** any drivers, you *must* obtain the proper kernel headers
  [Reference Debian Wiki:](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers)
  `$ sudo apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
  `$ sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

---

#### Part 2:

- Now it gets tricky: Disable the default nouveau driver:
  `$ sudo echo blacklist nouveau > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf`
  `$ sudo update-initramfs -u`
- Reboot to multi-user runlevel. *#**This will disable the GUI after reboot!!!***
  `$ systemctl set-default multi-user.target` 
  `$ systemctl reboot`

---

<kbd>**NOTE WELL**</kbd>: *When you restart your computer, everything you do will be from the command line.*

---

- From command line (or Safe Mode), navigate to directory where you downloaded the NVIDIA run file:
  `$ sudo bash NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-your.version#.run`
- During installation, you'll be asked questions, say YES to everything and install NVIDIA driver. After reboot, **SCREEN SHOULD START UP USING YOUR GRAPHICS CARD.**
- Remind your computer to use the GUI every time it starts up:
  `$ systemctl set-default graphical.target`
  `sudo reboot`

---

#### Part 3:

NVIDIA is good to go, but Blender still won't recognize your GPU because CUDA needs to be downloaded with nvidia-cuda-toolkit.

- [Download/Install CUDA Debian Installer](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-quick-start-guide/index.html#debian-x86_64-deb) from CUDA docs
- Reboot the system to load the NVIDIA drivers
- **Set up the development environment by modifying the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables**.
- [From Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#CUDA), install nvidia-cuda-toolkit picking up any missing pieces:
  `$ apt install nvidia-cuda-dev nvidia-cuda-toolkit`
- Update everything with `$ sudo apt update`
- Reboot computer: `$ systemctl reboot`
- Open Blender, check Edit --> Preferences --> System, and it should now recognize your GPU.